# Limiting a SUM in SSAS MDX calculated measure to only certain members of a dimension, filtering using multiple levels of hierarchy

Tags: ssas, mdx, cube

I have a complex financial data cube for which I am trying to create a calculated measure for net income, based on certain members of an "account" hierarchy. I want however to be able to drill down to see the individual figures making this up if so desired (the end user will be looking at results in Tableau).

I started with something like:

```
SUM(
{[Account].[Hierarchy].[Hierarchy Level 4].&[Level 4 Account 1],
[Account].[Hierarchy].[Hierarchy Level 4].&[Level 4 Account 2],
[Account].[Hierarchy].[Hierarchy Level 4].&[Level 4 Account 3]},
[Measures].[Amount])
```

This runs into issues if I wanted to drill into the figures. Note that I don't want account 4 included in the sum. It returns the same value for each row (it shows separate values correctly for unrelated dimensions):

| Hierarchy Level 4 | Amount | My Measure | Desired Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Level 4 Account 1 | 100 | 600 | 100 |
| Level 4 Account 2 | 200 | 600 | 200 |
| Level 4 Account 3 | 300 | 600 | 300 |
| Level 4 Account 4 | 400 | 600 | 0 |
| **Grand Total** | 1000 | 600 | 600 |

I managed to get something to work with an intersection, but ran into another problem.
I want to specify the set to sum using members at different levels of the account hierarchy.
My current expression is:

```
SUM(Intersect({
[Account].[Hierarchy].[Hierarchy Level 4].&[Level 4 Account 1], -- Falls within Level 3 account 1
[Account].[Hierarchy].[Hierarchy Level 4].&[Level 4 Account 2], -- Falls within Level 3 account 1
[Account].[Hierarchy].[Hierarchy Level 4].&[Level 4 Account 3], -- Falls within Level 3 account 2
[Account].[Hierarchy].[Hierarchy Level 3].&[Level 3 Account 3], -- want everything in level 3 account 3
[Account].[Hierarchy].[Hierarchy Level 3].&[Level 3 Account 4] -- want everything in level 3 account 4
}, [Account].[Hierarchy].CurrentMember), 
[Measures].[Amount])
```

This gives me:

| Hierarchy Level 3 | Hierarchy Level 4 | Amount | My Measure | Desired Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Level 3 Account 1 | Level 4 Account 1 | 100 | 100 | 100 |
| Level 3 Account 1 | Level 4 Account 2 | 200 | 200 | 200 |
| Level 3 Account 2 | Level 4 Account 3 | 300 | 300 | 300 |
| Level 3 Account 2 | Level 4 Account 4 | 400 | null | 0 |
| Level 3 Account 3 | Level 4 Account 5 | 100 | null | 100 |
| Level 3 Account 3 | Level 4 Account 5 | 200 | null | 200 |
| Level 3 Account 4 | Level 4 Account 6 | 300 | null | 300 |
| Level 3 Account 4 | Level 4 Account 7 | 400 | null | 400 |
| Level 3 Account 5 | Level 4 Account 8 | 100 | null | 0 |
| Level 3 Account 5 | Level 4 Account 9 | 200 | null | 0 |
| **Grand Total** |  | 2300 | null | 1600 |

The nulls are obviously equivalent to 0 so that's fine except for the total. The trouble is that I want it to pull through everything in those two members of Level 3.

If however I only go down to level 3 in the results I will only get figures for the items in the set defined at level 3:

| Hierarchy Level 3 | Amount | My Measure | Desired Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Level 3 Account 1 | 300 | null | 300 |
| Level 3 Account 2 | 700 | null | 300 |
| Level 3 Account 3 | 300 | 300 | 300 |
| Level 3 Account 4 | 700 | 700 | 700 |
| Level 3 Account 5 | 300 | null | 0 |
| **Grand Total** | 2300 | null | 1600 |

Am I going about this the wrong way? I have to do it all in a calculated measure because I am doing this within Tableau.

How can I get it to sum if the current account is in either of the appropriate hierarchy levels?